# Saving images on the server's file system

Tags: c#, asp.net

I got this code that should help me save an image to the servers file system:

```
      if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
    {

        string ImgName = FileUpload1.FileName;

        FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~").ToString() + "\\" + ImgName);

        Stream imgStream = FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream;

        Bitmap bmThumb = new Bitmap(imgStream);

        System.Drawing.Image im = bmThumb.GetThumbnailImage(100, 100, null, IntPtr.Zero);

        im.Save(Server.MapPath("~").ToString() + "\\ThumbNail_" + ImgName);

    }
```

I dont know why they convert the image to a Thumbnail.. All I need is the image to be saved to the files system and retreived as a small image (for avatar)..

I save the filename as nvarchar(50) in my database.

My question is how do I retrieve the image from the filesystem. (I can get its path from the database, which is: `Server.MapPath("~").ToString() + "\\ThumbNail_" + ImgName`

Is all I need to do:

```
ImageControl1.imageUrl=Server.MapPath("~").ToString() + "\\ThumbNail_" + ImgName;
```

Will the image appear in my ImageControl or not.

Can you criticize my code and add to it..cause it is the first time that i try to save and retrieve from the filesystem.

Will all that process work on my visual studio 2010 local server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Server.MapPath` provides an absolute path to the image on the server. In order to serve the image to the client you need the relative path. So you may try using the [ResolveUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.resolveurl.aspx) method:

```
ImageControl1.ImageUrl = ResolveUrl("~/ThumbNail_" + ImgName);
```

or if I remember correctly the Image control already does this and you don't need to explicitly call `ResolveUrl`, so the following might also work:

```
ImageControl1.ImageUrl = "~/ThumbNail_" + ImgName;
```

Comment: Why do i need to use the thumNail Can i remove it?

Comment: @WithFlyingColors, I don't know. Simply use the name of the image that you want to display as it is stored on your file system. If you have a file called `ImgName` in the root of your website you could use `ImageControl1.ImageUrl = "~/" + ImgName;`.

Comment: Is there a way to check that the file is actually an image and what size and weight the image is?

Comment: @WithFlyingColors, yes, there is: you could attempt loading it into an `Image` object: `Image.FromFile(...)` and if this succeeds use the resulting Width and Height properties.

Answer (score 1):

Thumbnail will reduce your actual image, so that it will display on avatar of your site without any distortion. You can also use image without creating thumbnail but users will upload images in different rations (width and height) , they might get distorted while displaying. Hence thumbnail will make proportional sizes of all uploaded images.

Comment: Yes, at least all ur images will be in fixed size and also looks good while displaying as avatar. Its good to use.

Comment: How can i decide on their sizes? How can i fit the thumnail picture to my picture control?

Comment: It is up to you..you can set the width and height of your image control where you will show avtar..for example if your image control is 200 X 200 then your thumbnail should be 200 X 200. You can decide dimension of image control according to your page layout. I hope it helps.